# Убрать стиль текста XML

Tags: c#, xml

Здравствуйте. Имеется XML документ, который парсится методом `XDocument.Parse()`. Затем нужно его перевести в тип данных (`string`). Делаю передом методом: `XDocument.Parse().ToString()` и вывожу в консоль `Console.WriteLine()` но выводится вот это:

```
<iq to="masterserver@k01/custom_server" id="uid00000068" type="get" from="5@k01/Client" xmlns="jabber:client">
  <query xmlns="urn:cryonline:k01">
    <setcurrentclass current="4" />
  </query>
</iq>
```

Данные передаются от сервера клиенту,и этот стиль XML сохраняется.
Но нужно, чтобы данный документ потерял стиль:

```
<iq to="masterserver@k01/custom_server" id="uid00000068" type="get" from="5@k01/Client" xmlns="jabber:client"><query xmlns="urn:cryonline:k01"><setcurrentclass current="4" /></query></iq>
```

Как можно такое сделать?

Comment: `new Regex(@"\r?\n\s*").Replace(text, "")`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В `XDocument` есть [специальная перегрузка `ToString()`, принимающая `SaveOptions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb551415(v=vs.110).aspx), просто воспользуйтесь этим:

```
Console.WriteLine(XDocument.Parse(text).ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting));
```

Comment: О, круто! Не нашёл сходу.

Answer (score 2):

Правильнее всего сохранять из `XDocument`, задавая опции форматирования:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
using (var w = new StringWriter(sb))
    xd.Save(w, SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
var result = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: Спасибо за ваш способ, который вы оставили вначале, но он оказался немного костыльным). Способ Андрея думаю подходит больше :)

Comment: @ИльяПетров: Да, его способ намного изящнее.