# Представить строку в xml формате

Tags: c#, xml, строки

Из БД достаю информацию типа `byte[]`, преобразовываю в `string`. В результате получаю длинную строку с xml данными:

```
<DEV BC="???"><TEST User="??" Name="???" Time="???" Res="???"><STEP Name="???" Res="???"><TITLE>... и т.д.
```

Как можно разбить это в нормальное представление?

```
<DEV BC="???">
<TEST User="??" Name="???" Time="???" Res="???">
<STEP Name="???" Res="???">
<TITLE>... и т.д.
```

Был вариант с использованием Replace:

```
 richTextBox2.Text = Regex.Replace(Encoding.UTF8.GetString((byte[])reader["AnsData"]), "</", "\r\n$&", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
 richTextBox2.Text = Regex.Replace(richTextBox2.Text, ">", "$&\r\n", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Но это очень тупо и результат совсем не тот, который хотелось бы иметь.

Comment: Там валидный XML лежит?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Меня уверяли что да. Возможности проверить нет.

Comment: Связанный вопрос (там обратная задача): https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/809605/218063

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если у вас хранится валидный XML, то загрузите его в `XDocument`:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(text);
```

и воспользуйтесь его методом `ToString()` без параметров (по умолчанию XML как раз выводится в человекопонятном виде):

```
richTextBox2.Text = xdoc.ToString();
```